# Have somebody doing something?

Tags: american-english, canadian-english

What does this mean if a standing comedian says

```
I can't have you guys being a.. umm.. English audience and going "Oh hmm hmm"
```

This is from 3:30 of 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIE1xkF8RZE

I know he's asking the audience to laugh when they want to laugh.

But "have you being an English audience" sounds completely unfamiliar.

Is this grammatical or at least is this how natives use English?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a common phrase - essentially equivalent to the speaker saying that they can't/won't allow a situation to exist.

For example, if a friend confided in me that he was feeling sad, I might reply "We can't have that!" and take him out to do something fun.